# Loading ENVI file into ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, import, envi

I received a series of *.img files with a single .hdr file that contains the necessary georeferencing information (i.e., samples, lines, coord system, etc.). I presume this is an ENVI header file since the first lines in the .hdr file are

ENVI 
description = {
...

The img files display in ArcGIS with no problem, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get Arc to recognize the header file, or how to set this information in the raster after its loaded. Ideally, it would be great if I could pull the entire series of img files into a single catalog.

Comment: I think you are fine to go. Just set the projection in ArcCatalog and check the other information is correct in properties.

Comment: It looks that way to me too, and when I use the ArcGIS "Add data"  button  it loads the img just fine. But it doesn't load anything from the header file - no projection, no scale info. If I assign the projection, it still doesn't know "where" the img is supposed to be. Perhaps I am using the wrong tool to load the file? I would appreciate advice on how to have the header recognized during the load or, failing that, the easiest way to set the header information manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had posted the entire ENVI header file, the solution would likely have been clear to most. Turns out I missed the fact that the header file had no georeferencing information. The key line in the ENVI header file that allows ArcGIS to correctly georeference the image file is:

map info = {Geographic Lat/Lon, 1.0000, 1.0000, -139.00000000, 56.00000000, 1.3943160000e-002, 9.0090100000e-003, WGS-84, units=Degrees}

Without this block, ArcGIS understandably has no idea what to do with the image.

Mea culpa. Yet another sorry example of a user not posting enough information. Apologies.